# Count rational numbers in lowest terms in $[0,1]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

I was wondering if there is a formula for the count of rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms in $[0,1]$ similar to the sequence in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1901760/454513).

For example:

- For $q = 1$ we have two: $\{\frac{0}{1}, \frac{1}{1}\}$
- For $q = 2$ we have one: $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$
- For $q = 3$ we have two: $\{\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}\}$
- For $q = 4$ we have two: $\{\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}\}$
- For $q = 5$ we have four: $\{\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}\}$
- For $q = 6$ we have two: $\{\frac{1}{6}, \frac{5}{6}\}$
- For $q = 7$ we have six: $\{\frac{1}{7}, \frac{2}{7}, \frac{3}{7}, \frac{4}{7}, \frac{5}{7}, \frac{6}{7}\}$
- and so on...

So we have a total of $19$ rational numbers in lowest terms with $q \le 7$. I'd be happy with the total count for all $q \le N$ too.

Comment: $p/q$ is in lowest terms if $p$ and $q$ are coprime, so your question is about counting the number of numbers coprime to $q$ which is $\phi(q)$ with $\phi$ euler totient function.

Comment: Of related interest: [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence)

Comment: @hardmath Spot on comment ... I am sure OP would be interested. Hardy and Wright's book has some material on this which makes some useful connections with related topivcs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is related to [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). In particular, the total number of fractions $p/q$, where $1\le p < q$, and $\gcd(p,q)=1$ equals $\varphi(q)$, where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is the Euler's totient function. Consequently, the required number of fractions is 
$$2+\sum_{q=2}^{N} \varphi(q).$$